# Thus and commas - is this correct?

Tags: commas

"While most of us associate it with the supernatural or magic, thus reject its existence, it’s been studied by researchers since years." - do you think that this sentence is correct? I'm reading about "thus" and commas and I got totally confused.

Comment: *Thus* could use a comma, but it would add clutter. Another question is why not use *and* instead of *thus*?

Answer (score 1):

It's ungrammatical. Correct versions are:

- *While most of us associate it with the supernatural or magic, and thus reject its existence, it’s been studied by researchers for many years.*
- *While most of us associate it with the supernatural or magic, thus rejecting its existence, it’s been studied by researchers for many years.*

The parenthetical could be offset by brackets or dashes in each case, giving more measured pauses and adding gravitas to the parenthetical statement.